# Open source application to track and manage low level plans

Tags: open-source

I work in a team of 5. We track our low level plans in spreadsheets. This always results in some sort of miscommunication, delay as it is not updated or out of order. Are there any open source tool that can be used to manage low level plans/stories for a small team efficiently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I'd try using [Planner](http://live.gnome.org/Planner/About). I use it to manage my little projects, as I forget what I was debugging and when I did it. It's clean and simple, and it's got Linux and Windows binaries (no idea about Mac).

Here's a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: This is one of the reasons I love using GNOME software; it's just so simple, yet there is a program for virtually everything.